# How to pass instance method as a delegate

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have this method that I use with *EF*

```
RetryGetWithExpression<city, List<city>>(u => u.Take(10).ToList());

public static TValue RetryGetWithExpression<T, TValue>(
        Func<ObjectSet<T>, TValue> func)
    where T : class
{
    var entitySet = entitiesContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    return func(entitySet);
}
```

The above code works with the table entities generated by EF. What I am trying to do is to change the code in such way that it works with stored procedures.

This is the code that *executes the SP*:

```
Entities G = new Entities();
ObjectResult<retrieveMedia_Result> F = G.retrieveMedia(1);
```

When I try to convert RetryGetWithExpression to accept SPs, I get a problem that retrieveMedia is instance method and I cant pass it as u.retrieveMedia(1)

```
RetryGetWithExpression<Entities, ObjectResult<retrieveMedia_Result>>(
    u => u.retrieveMedia(1));

public static TValue RetryGetWithExpression<T, TValue>(
        Func<ObjectSet<T>, TValue> func)
    where T : class
{

}
```

How to change the above code so that It works with SPs?

Comment: So you need to pass the extra parameters for delegate in the signature of you function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RetryGetWithExpression<ObjectResult<retrieveMedia_Result>>(u => u.retrieveMedia(1));

public static TValue RetryGetWithExpression<TValue>(Func<Entities, TValue> func)
{
    return func(entitiesContext);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. retrieveMedia is not related to retrieveMedia_Result.

Comment: @user1662812 What is the return type of `retrieveMedia`?

Comment: @user1662812 then use `RetryGetWithExpression<retrieveMedia_Result>(u => u.retrieveMedia(1));` instead

Comment: This doesn't compile and fails on Func<Entities,

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like,

```
public static TValue RetryGetWithExpression<TParam, TValue>(
        Func<TParam, TValue> func,
        TParam parameter)
{
    return func(parameter);
}
```

Which you would call like,

```
Entities g = new Entities();
ObjectResult<retrieveMedia_Result> f = 
    RetryGetWithExpression<int?, ObjectResult<retrieveMedia_Result>>(
        g.retrieveMedia,
        1);
```

but, it seems pretty pointless, because all you want to do is pass a function delegate and call it.

Comment: This dose not compile because it fails on this line:  g.retrieveMedia,
With error: The type arguments for method 'RetryGetWithExpression<TParam,TValue>(System.Func<TParam,TValue>, TParam)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Okay, I'll specify them explicity for you then.

Comment: I've made the assumption that retrieveMedia accepts an `int`.

Comment: I still get an error on the same line g.retrieveMedia,: No overload for 'retrieveMedia(int?)' matches delegate 'System.Func<int, ObjectResult<retrieveMedia_Result>>'

Comment: okay, that because my assumption about `int` is incorrect, as the message clearly states.

Comment: I've changed the code to `int?` to match the signature of `retrieveMedia`

Comment: Ok this works, but I hate this solution because it is completely counterintuitive. It is a problem that I have to provide the parameters in this strange way, where I have to rely on parameter order. What a mess it will be if I have 10 parameters, I will have to match all the types with the values and make sure that the position is right.

Comment: @user1662812, and you will have to overload the method to accept a variable numbers of parameters. If all this function does is call the delegate, just remove the function and call the stored procedure directly.